# Building array of 'truthy' rule conditions

Tags: javascript

I'm running a lot of functions to build a mongoDb request. Based on their response (if not `falsy`) I'm appending the return values to an array `ruleConditions[]` which is used later.

Currently I'm doing it this way:

```
//building ruleConditions
var ruleConditions = {$and: []};

var fromConditions = mongoRequestsHelper.getFromConditions(rule.from);
if (fromConditions) ruleConditions.$and.push(fromConditions);

//and 4 similar blocks
```

Is there any way to avoid unneeded variables creation (`carTypesConditions`...)?

Calling functions twice like:

```
if (mongoRequestsHelper.getFromConditions(rule.moversFilter)) ruleConditions.push(mongoRequestsHelper.getFromConditions(rule.moversFilter))
```

is not a good idea obviously.

Comment: `if(getMoversConditions()) conditions.push(getMoversConditions())`. Depending on how long it takes to run your functions, this is a bad approach performance-wise, though, because it requires your to call each function twice.

Comment: @connexo updated question before your proposal :) I know about running twice variant, not good for me.

Comment: Be aware that you are not checking for `false`, but for *falsy*. If a function returns either of `0`, `""`, `null` or `undefined`, your condition will also omit that push. I'm saying that because I altered your question before and changed that to *falsy* - which you changed back to `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up, you should really be using more modern variable definitions (using `let` and `const` instead of `var`).

As for your conditional processing for the mongoDB clauses, the simpler way to process the data would be to accumulate all the clauses in to a single temporary array, and then filter that array in to the actual query clause. For example, consider:

```
const clauses = [
    mongoRequestsHelper.getFromConditions(rule.A),
    mongoRequestsHelper.getFromConditions(rule.B),
    mongoRequestsHelper.getFromConditions(rule.C),
    mongoRequestsHelper.getFromConditions(rule.D),
    ......
];

const ruleConditions = {
    // filter out non-truthy clauses
    $and: clauses.filter(clause => clause)
};
```

Comment: if I would have single condition, is it possible to do it in one line? Something like `var type = options.carType || false`, but instead of false do nothing?